# Не применяются шрифты внутри <form>

Tags: html, css

У меня импортирован и привязан к тегу html, body один шрифт. Всё что внутри тега `<form>` имеет свой шрифт, и как буд-то не видит тот что я привязал.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: "Space Grotesk", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input__name">
    <label for="name" class="input__title">Cardholder name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="e.g. Jane Appleseed" class="long-input" required />
  </div>
</form>
```

Вот некий пример моей формы, у меня ни в `<label>` ни в `<input>` не применяется шрифт.

Что делать?

Comment: Покажи в вопросе как сделана форма. Т.е. сделай некий тестовый пример.

Comment: Шрифты подключены? Если в разметку добавить другой элемент помимо формы, шрифты другие?

Comment: Да, я импортировал шрифт, и добавил его в селектор html, body. Он ко всем другим элементам, заголовком и т.д. применяется. Но только в теге <form> не хочет. Мне надо чтобы он к label и placeholder так же применялся. Я могу конечно отдельно к ним подключить шрифты, но это уже лишний код.

Comment: По историческим причинам шрифт в кнопках/полях ввода не наследуется от body, а задаётся явно браузером. Т.е. проблема не в теге form, а в тегах button/input/select и т.д.

Comment: `input, button, textarea, select { font-family: inherit; }` можно починить примерно так

Comment: Да, помогло. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input {
  font: inherit;
}
```

Для других контролов стоит тоже прописать, если они используются.